# Why should I add Gradle Dependency?

Tags: android

I am following a [udacity tutorial](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud836/lessons/4619208555/concepts/45821199720923) and I can make the program working without
"Add Gradle Dependency"
`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'`

Why should I add Gradle Dependency? What does `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0'` do?

Comment: Please read through google documentation it will give you in-depth 
 https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages
moreover the tutorial you are following must be quite old because these version for the support library is quite very old 6+ year old.
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/rev-archive#rev22-1-0

Comment: Please accept my answer if it helped you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

***Why you need AppCompat***

It is a set of support libraries which allow for backwards compatibility(i.e. making newer features work with older android versions).

***What it(visibly) is***

AppCompat is just ActionBarCompat. Every activity extends AppCompat.
The action bar is the bar at the top of every app. You can disable it using the theme attribute `NoActionBar`. If you would like to, add this in your themes.xml file `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` as the parent.

And from the docs:

> AppCompat (aka ActionBarCompat) started out as a backport of the
> Android 4.0 ActionBar API for devices running on Gingerbread,
> providing a common API layer on top of the backported implementation
> and the framework implementation. AppCompat v21 delivers an API and
> feature-set that is up-to-date with Android 5.0